# Como ter novamente acesso ao Label no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Coloquei um Label no form, editei seu nome para ficar vazio, renomeei e até ai tudo bem, sendo que não consigo mais seleciona-lo no form para manipulação.

Ele funciona dentro da aplicação trazendo o ID do cadastro, preciso manipular pois está desalinhado com o conteúdo do form mas não consigo mais acesso a ele.

Estou usando Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Tem uma janela chamada **document outline**, nela vão estar todos os controles de form e ao clicar em um, ele será selecionado no form designer.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas seu comentário pode vir como resposta ?

Comment: Postei como resposta, eu estava esperando o Visual Studio abrir para poder postar uma imagem, mas não tá dando muito certo xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem uma janela chamada *document outline*, nela vão estar todos os controles de form e ao clicar em um, ele será selecionado no form designer.

> Vou colocar uma imagem assim que meu computador colaborar e eu conseguir abrir o Visual Studio -_-

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Como mencionado pelo @Linq nos comentários, você pode usar a janela `Document Outline` e acessar qualquer controle no `Form`

[image]

Ou, na janela `Properties` você tem um combo, com os controles do `Form` também:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado